# prevent duplicate comments using wp_insert_comment

Tags: comments, facebook, duplicates

i am trying to import facebook comments to wordpress
what iam doing is get the graph of the facebook post
Comments, json decode it 
then i import the comment via this code

so my code so far is

```
foreach($comm_no as $answer_id => $v) {
$time = current_time('mysql');
$data = array(
'comment_post_ID' => $post->ID,
'comment_author' => $v->from->name,
'comment_author_email' => '',
'comment_author_url' => 'https://www.facebook.com/'.$v->from->id,
'comment_content' => $v->message,
'comment_type' => '',
'comment_parent' => 0,
'user_id' => 5,
'comment_author_IP' => '127.0.0.1',
'comment_agent' => 'egysp.com',
'comment_date' => $time,
 'comment_approved' => 1,
);
wp_insert_comment($data);`
```

this code is in my single php

> the proplem is every time the post is visisted the comments imported again an again an again so i have like 1000 comment of duplicate comments

can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Have you considered using wp cron? It can be used to schedule events to run at certain time or interval of times.

Comment: Yes and wp secluded event ,but no use .if i used cron or event it will import the comments again every time , i want tobuse wp_filter_comment but idont know the proper way to use it

Comment: Literally if you import comments repeatedly then they will be imported repeatedly. You need to decide which precisely are conditions that make comment duplicate and how to handle it. Making requests to a remote system on every load is probably horrible for performance too btw.

Comment: @Rarst that waht i am tring to do for over a week now ,
and literally I Have no idea what ican Do next .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please Note:** Doing this will be very slow! It would be much better to do one (or preferably both) of the following instead:

1. Use wp_cron to do this on a regular basis
2. Instead of grabbing all comments, the first time it runs set at timestamp in the options table after it completes. Each time afterwards, read the timestamp and grab just those comments made since the timestamp... and update the timestamp on completion

**That being said:**

To do this, you should check for duplicates before adding the comment, which requires deciding what constitutes a duplicate comment.

Assuming the author_url and the comment itself would work, you could do something like the following:

```
function my_comment_already_exists($author_url, $comment) {
    $already_exists = false;
    global $wpdb;
    # try grabbing the first 40 characters of the comment. Hopefully that will make it unique
    # also changed select from 1 as it_exists to comment_ID in case prepare broke that part
    $comment_bit = substr($comment, 0, 40);
    $like_bit = $wpdb->esc_like( $comment_bit ) . '%';
    $query = "SELECT comment_ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}comments WHERE comment_author_url = %s AND comment_content LIKE %s";
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( $query, $author_url, $like_bit );
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
    if ( is_null($results) ) {
       # error
       if ( $wpdb->last_error ) {
           echo "<p>Error: {$wpdb->last_error}</p>";
       }
    } else if ( is_array($results) && 0 < count($results) ) {
        $already_exists = true;
    }
    return $already_exists;
}
```

Then, for each comment, you could do something like:

```
if ( !my_comment_already_exists( 'https://www.facebook.com/'.$v->from->id, $v->message ) ) {
    wp_insert_comment($data);
}
```

Comment: not working , i tried the cron job but ididnt know how to make .can you give me an example how to make it work with cron job ?imean i know how to make a cron job but every time i do a cron job the comments fetched again how to make it stop if there is no new comments ?

Comment: Updated the query and code a bit. Also, cron by itself wouldn't fix the fundamental issue, which is grabbing all posts. If you can grab just comments since a certain time stamp, you could grab the comments, process them, and, if successful, save the timestamp to the options table. Then the next time, grab the timestamp from the options table and grab only comments since then. No more need to even check for duplicates. Can open graph grab only since timestamp X? If so, that would be the clean choice.

Comment: WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ربنا يصبركم بس انتي عن'%'' at line 1 for query SELECT comment_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_author_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/10202311166500072' AND comment_comment like ''ربنا يصبركم بس انتي عن'%' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/flat-theme/single.php'), get_fbcomm, my_comment_already_exists


not working and thats what show is error log , thanks man

Comment: Alright, query fixed via esc_like hopefully. I wasn't sure how to do that. Guess you do learn something new every day.

Comment: WordPress database error Unknown column 'comment_comment' in 'where clause' for query SELECT comment_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_author_url,
i think we are geting close :D

Comment: Sorry. I must be really tired. updated the query. It should have been comment_content, not comment_comment.

Comment: you were right , thats slows the site alot , so i give it up that way i will figure some thing else , any way thanks